# Keeping a snapshot of a bamboo plan

Tags: bamboo

I have a bamboo plan to run selenium automation tests on my app.

This bamboo plan has parallel stages to run selenium tests simultaneously on multiple agents. This is done to save time. If all tests were executed sequentially, it would take about 10 hours.

When the app which is tested evolves with time, more parallel stages are added to the bamboo plan.

When a bug fix is provided for an older version of the app, I need to run the test plan with at the correct position of the test suite git repository. I do this by using a plan variable to specify the test suite repository branch.

But, the problem is, bamboo plan also evolves with the application because I add more parallel stages when the tested app evolves. So, reverting to the correct source control position of the test suite repository is not sufficient. The bamboo plan also should revert to the state it was when the bug fixed release was originally given.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [Bamboo Specs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-specs-894743906.html)(a newly introduced feature since Bamboo 6.0). This allows the entire configuration of Bamboo plans to be stored as Java source code. You can modify this code and [publish the plan](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-create-a-simple-plan-with-bamboo-specs-894743911.html) as desired. You can also extend this by automating the changes using [Repository Stored Specs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-bamboo-specs-stored-in-bitbucket-server-938641946.html).

All you have to do is to [export your existing plan](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/exporting-existing-plans-to-bamboo-specs-894743917.html) by going to the respective plan's configuration page and click on  `Actions > View plan as Bamboo Specs`. Cross-check the generated code with [Bamboo Specs reference manual](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/latest) and to compare original and generated plan.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, bamboo version I have is 5. I will have to wait until my company upgrades bamboo to version 6.

Comment: Yes, Good luck with that :) The latest versions even support YAML(https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-bamboo-specs-yaml-stored-in-bitbucket-server-941616819.html) to construct simple plans.